# Битрикс - перенос сайта на другой домен

Tags: битрикс

Решаю задачу по переносу сайта на Битриксе. Возникла проблема. Из консоли *.nix распаковал из архива дистрибутив уже ранее развернутого сайта, который был запакован в формат taz.

Мои действия далее:

1. Распаковал архив командой tar.
2. Сделал запрос к моей базе данных. Там база называется условно mybase. Смотрю логин и пароль пользователя root. Для этого выполняю команду:

   `select * from mysql.user where user = 'root';`

Оттуда получаю логин и пароль.

3. На ftp-сервере я прописываю  в

   `/bitrix/.settings.php`
   и в 
   `/bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php`

   доступы к базе: имя базы, пользователь root и пароль взятый из базы, тем не менее получаю ошибку:

   `Warning:
    require_once(/home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog.php):
    failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/header.php on line 1
    Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog.php'
    (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/header.php on line 1`

Заливал на сервер, файл restore.php для переноса данных, но там также выдавало много ошибок:

> Warning:
>   include_once(/home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/modules/main/include/urlrewrite.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/urlrewrite.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/modules/main/include/urlrewrite.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/urlrewrite.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include_once(/home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/404.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/urlrewrite.php on line 4
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/404.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/urlrewrite.php on line 4

Как с этим бороться, и в чем вообще причина? На битриксе работал немного и это было давно и неправда, потому прошу помощи у специалистов, кто может подсказать по этому поводу. Буду благодарен услышать ответы и советы от людей работающих с Битриксом.

Comment: Вообще-то у Битрикса есть файлик restore.php для подобных действий, который выполняет перенос архивов, распаковку и развертку дампа базы. Вы могли через консоль не целиком распаковать архив, если он был не из одной части, да и вобще для переноса стоит использовать штатные средства если они есть.

Comment: я такой использовал, но он тоже выдает ошибки мне: вот такая там талмуда. Смотрите мой вопрос, дополнил его.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с правами доступа.

1) Проверьте права пользователя, под которым работает bitrix и Web-сервер.

2) Проверьте права доступа к файлу `/home/kprealty/www/kprealty.sy.pro/bitrix/header.php`

3) Проверьте selinux `#getenforce`

Comment: 1. Сижу под юзером, сколько прав у него не знаю, честно говоря. 2. Там все хорошо, права 777. 3. Команды в линуксе не использовал, затрудняюсь сказать, что мне должна дать эта команда.

Comment: Права 777 где? У всех фалов во всех директориях и поддиреткориях? У вас _ТОЧНО_ проблема с правами. `Getenforce` должен дать ответ. В каком режиме selinux. enforcing, permissive или disabled

Comment: да с правами... ничего не могу поделать. Жду решения от руководства, по поводу расширения моих прав... Спасибо за ответы.